# SVN: How to find latest files that were merged in my project

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Please note that I'm new to SVN and TortoiseSVN. I'll fix this asap. But at the current moment I've got a question:

1) I have prepared the commit in TortoiseSvn (selected the files and clicked "Commit").

2) After I pressed OK, I've got a message that some files have beed changed in the repo, so I have to update. The files with conflicts were marked red.

3) I clicked "Update". I've expected to recieve the dialog "resolve the conflicts". But instead I've got the list of updated and merged (marked green) files.

*So I think I've somehow skipped the "resolve conflicts" phase. I've expected to see some error messages but there were none...*

4) Then I've presssed "Commit" again and this time the commit was successful.

---

The problem is: How can I view which files were merged? Can I restrict such automatically file merging? Was there any file merging at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't do the merging manually then the merging must have been automatic.

If the changes you've made are not related to the incoming changes in the update then it is simple for svn to do the merge automatically.

A Conflict will only happen if you have changed a line that has also been altered elsewhere in the time between the update before your edits and the update after your edits.